# How to implement grpc - java async server?

Tags: asynchronous, grpc, grpc-java

When I look at the grpc-java auto-generated classes for the server calls and the sample examples given in the grpc-java git repo, I can see we extend the ImplBase class and override the service method. Like below:

`static class communicationImpl extends communicationImplBase`

In C++, to implement a Async Service we extend our implementation using AsyncService instead of Service class. But in java's generated Grpc class, i cannot see another class that is named/starting with Async. The only Server related class i see in there is the one ending with ImplBase. So how do i set up my server to process requests asynchronously in grpc-Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ImplBase` class **is** the async interface, although for unary and server-streaming method it can be implemented in a blocking style.

Comment: Thank you Kun! if I set up a fixed size thread pool like below in `ServerBuilder.forPort(port).executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16)).addService(myService).build();`                                                    And if my service method involves a DB acess before calling an onNext and onCompleted, does it mean each individual thread that is processing this service method is blocked on this call?

Comment: Yes. Since the given thread pool is used to run your service handler which calls into DB, the DB call will block in the thread pool.

Comment: If say I can expect 4000 client connections at a time, this thread pool size would be a wrong choice? (16 Thread pool size was based on the number of cores we may have on the server that it is running) Is there any way I can improve this using gRPC?

Comment: The thread size doesn't need to match the number of connections. The number of threads that are actually blocked on DB access at a time can be smaller or larger than that. The key factors are the requests per second received, and the latency of the DB access. If the threads don't turn out to be enough, requests will be backlogged in the thread pool's queue.

Comment: You will want to employ flow-control so that the queue doesn't blow up your memory. You can cast `StreamObserver` to `CallStreamObserver` to get flow-control API.

Comment: Thank you Kun! That was very helpful! I couldn't find any documentation on similar use cases on grpc-java website. I have posted another question here related to managedChannelBuilder at the client end here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119082/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-clients-that-a-grpc-java-managedchannelbuilder-can.