# What is the maximum number of clients that a grpc-java managedchannelbuilder can handle?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

When we create a managedChannelBuilder and use this to call a grpc-java service call, how many clients can we serve with this? Doesn't this channel be shutdown after individual service call? 
Say I have a REST interface which accepts REST calls from a browser 
and from within these REST Service methods, I am making grpc client calls to an independent grpc server. Also I can expect client connections in the range of [4000-5000] concurrently.
 How well can I make use of this managedChannelBuilder. Do I need just one? Or do I need to pool multiple channelbuilders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I'd suggest using a single `ManagedChannel` per endpoint when your code can be easily structured to share it. `ManagedChannel` multiplexes RPCs and is thread-safe, so it can handle multiple RPCs concurrently.

In rarer cases of high very high throughput, it may make sense to use more than one `ManagedChannel`. [Eventually](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7957) `ManagedChannel` (or, maybe `Channel`) should have support for doing this natively.

Comment: Thank you Eric, that was very helpful! What could be a range you think as very high throughput?

Comment: Though ManagedChannel is thread safe StreamObserver onNext is not. You must sync onNext calls for the same StreamObserver, otherwise you'll get broken binary data exception on the other side.